# Is Boost_lockFree_SPSC_queue is really variable sized and data loss free?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, boost, blockingqueue

Hi I have planned to use boost SPSC queue. I have to have a listener which always listen for the incoming messages once it received it will put the message into a queue and return to wait again for new messages. And there a consumer which pop messages from the queue and process it.

Since I don’t want my listener to wait to get the lock to write into a queue I preferred `boost_lockfree_spsc_queue`. And I believed that size of the queue is vary if I set `fixed_sized<false>` while initialising the queue. But It seems it is not.

Following is my code:

```
boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<int, boost::lockfree::fixed_sized<false>> lockFreeQ{10};

void sharedQueue::lockFreeProduce()
{

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
       lockFreeQ.push(i);        
       cout<<"--"<<i<<endl;
    }

}
void sharedQueue::lockFreeConsume(){

for(int i = 0;  i <100; i++){

   /* Implement a blocking pop to the queue in order to waste cpu time  by busy waiting*/

        while(!(lockFreeQ.read_available() > 0))
           {
               //std::this_thread::yield();
                 std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(10));
           }

       cout<<"   ***"<<lockFreeQ.front()<<endl;
       lockFreeQ.pop();

   }

}

void sharedQueue:: TestLockFreeQueue()
{

   std::thread t1([this]() { this->lockFreeProduce(); });
   std::thread t2([this]() { this->lockFreeConsume(); });   
   t1.join();
   t2.join();
}
```

The output shows that loss of data.  The following is the partial result. but it misses number 87 ,92 for example.

```
**85
***86
***88
***90
***91
***93
***95
***96
***98
```

If it were variable sized it should extend the size of the queue and should not loose the data. It seems that it overwrites the data as explained [A consequence of the circular buffer is that when it is full and a subsequent write is performed, then it starts overwriting the oldest data.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).  In such case how can deal with this without loosing data?

Thanks

Comment: Your queue is still a circular buffer with max_size of 10. The only thing that changed with the policy is that, instead of using a stack array, it will use a dynamically allocated array.

Comment: What do you meant by “dynamically allocated array”? Does it mean the size of the array will increase incase the queue is full?

Comment: I meant that the array would be allocated by making use of the allocator. The size of the dynamically allocated array would be the size you passed in the constructor. The array size _would not_ be increased when queue is full, instead it will rewrite the data on the first index because the data structure used will always be a circular buffer of the size you passed in the constructor.

Comment: So, to conclude, you must choose a sufficiently high value while constructing the queue which can ensure in best case that the data would not be overwritten. Basically you cannot guarantee this behaviour using a circular queue because you never know when the consumer would crash or start processing slowly.

Comment: Ok so the size of the array won’t be more than 10 in any case. So once the array is full and there are data needs to be filled it just replace the old data. hence the data loss is unavoidable. Is there anyways to avoid data loss?

Comment: See my comment above. OR use a lock free list (1024cores.com). If you end up using list, make sure you bound it to some high value. You do not want your producer to fill up the list infinitely while the consumer is crashed or doing nothing.

Comment: I will move these comments to answer later as I do not see any similar questions asked earlier.

Comment: Yes I saw the previous comment. The site you referred is not working.

Comment: http://www.1024cores.net/

Comment: UpVoted for the link. Thanks Arun.

Answer (score 0):

Translating the comments to answer.

The way the policy works for `spsc_queue` is as below:

```
typedef typename mpl::if_c<runtime_sized,                                  
                           runtime_sized_ringbuffer<T, allocator>,
                           compile_time_sized_ringbuffer<T, capacity>
                          >::type ringbuffer_type;
```

In your case it chooses the `runtime_sized_ringbuffer` buffer instead of `compile_time_sized_ringbuffer`.

The difference between the both being that, in case of `runtime_sized_ringbuffer` the array of size (passed as argument to the constructor) is allocated using the `allocator` passed as the template parameter *and* in case of `compile_time_sized_ringbuffer` the array is allocated on stack.

So, if your queue size is large, you have to use `runtime_sized_ringbuffer` in place of `compile_time_sized_ringbuffer`.

That being the only difference, the underlying data structure is a `circular_buffer` in both cases. i.e. even in case of `runtime_sized_ringbuffer`, the oldest element would get overwritten once you are done writing to all the locations/index in the buffer. This is quite straight forward from the code below

```
static size_t next_index(size_t arg, size_t max_size)
{
  size_t ret = arg + 1;
  while (unlikely(ret >= max_size))
    ret -= max_size;
  return ret;
}
```

If you really need a lock free list data structure, you should look at the famous lock free list data structure by [Dmitry Vyukov](http://www.1024cores.net/)